# How to find the highest value from multiple array

Tags: java

- name|Math|Reading|Science|
- Bob |75.0|57.0|65.0|
- Tom |60.0|67.0|75.0|
- James|80.0|60.0|57.0|
- John|70.0|90.0|69.0|

From the above graph and below Java program, How do I find the person who gets highest Math score to change highest() method?

Maybe, my highest() method gets highest Math score, but I don't know how to connect the highest score and the person.

```
public class Test {
  // Assuming that the first line(name, Math, Reading, Science) is skipped
  static int NAME = 4;
  static int SCORE = 3;
  static String[] name = new String[NAME]; 
  static Double[][] score = new Double[NAME][SCORE];

　public static String highest() { 
      double max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NAME; i++) {
            if (max < score[i][0]) {
                max = score[i][0];
            }
        }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The highest Math score is" + highest());
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If the question is asking how to load data please tell me in the comments. I assume you have loaded the data correctly.

As I see you can find the names in the for loop you find the max math score. In that loop your `i` variable also can get the name like `name[i]`. The only thing you should do is you have to store the name of the student who has the highest score. Just edit your function like below.

```java
public static String highest() { 
      String highestScoreStudent= "";
      double max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NAME; i++) {
            if (max < score[i][0]) {
                max = score[i][0];
                highestScoreStudent = name[i];
            }
        }
      return highestScoreStudent;
  }
```

Comment: I already loaded the data, so your answer is helped me! Thank you so much